# I have got error TS2345: Argument of type X is not assignable to parameter of type Y

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I am recently working with angular 8. I'm a novice with this framework.

I'm trying to create an interface with new elements. I strangely notice that with the first two fields I have no problem. Instead when I go to insert new ones the following linting error message appears:

> ERROR in src/app/weatherObject/weather-class.ts(27,17): error TS2345:
>   Argument of type '{ cityName: any; degrees: number; impaction: number;
>   }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WeatherFeature'. Object
>   literal may only specify known properties, and 'impaction' does not
>   exist in type 'WeatherFeature'.

This is my interface:

```
interface WeatherFeature {
    cityName: string,
    degrees: number,
    impaction: number //REFUSED FIELD
    // sky: string //READY TO BE PUT, But as long as impaction doesn't work I can't put it!
}
```

And this is the class code on which I assign the values:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { WeatherForecastApiService } from '../weatherForecastApiService/weather-forecast-api.service';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class WeatherClass {

    public weatherFeature = new BehaviorSubject<WeatherFeature>(undefined);

    constructor(
        private wfas: WeatherForecastApiService,
    ) {
        this.retriver();
    }

    private retriver() {
        this.wfas.getItalyWeatherData('Pisa').subscribe((response) => {
            const ks: string[] = ['name', 'main', 'temp', 'pressure', 'weather'];
            console.log(response[ks[1]][ks[3]], response[ks[4]][0][ks[1]]);
            this.weatherFeature.next({
                cityName: response[ks[0]],
                degrees: Number((response[ks[1]][ks[2]] - 273.15).toFixed()),
                impaction: Number(response[ks[1]][ks[3]]) //WHY CAN I NOT PUT IT ???
            });
        });
    }
}
```

I can't understand why, although I expand the interface, I get that error message when I go to insert the new fields in the interface in the class file.
I hope it's a stupid mistake, a misunderstanding of mine, and nothing more.

Comment: This error usually occurs due to typos in the code. Please go through it thoroughly for typos. :)

Comment: but the typing errors are triggered immediately by the linter... I do not see them up to now...

Comment: @Memmo: He has meant typos not typing errors ;), which is true, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining an interface use semicolons `;` instead of commas `,` to separate properties.

```
export interface WeatherFeature {
    cityName: string;
    degrees: number;
    impaction: number;
}
```

Unless it's in the same file where used, do not forget to export/import it.

Comment: After TypeScript 1.6 it is allowed to use both [ ; ] or [ , ] as a delimiter in interfaces, isn't it?

Comment: You won't believe it...I've applied semicolons I've recompiled it all, fixing linting errors and magically everything worked...! I also trust [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58744992/8275210). Instead, putting `export` has created problems for me.

Comment: @PriyalalKoggalage that's correct, however at least for me it is more handy to use `;`, but also because of historical reason.
@Memmo what kind of problems exporting the interface are you talking about?

Comment: @mpro this one: `weather-feature.ts' is not a module.`

Comment: @Memmo Never got that one, especially I always put interfaces into separate files to easily reuse them in entire project.

Answer (score 1):

You probably edit wrong file with WeatherFeature, maybe .bak